# Local configuration for multinode rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration, load-balancing

I'd like to introduce per-machine configuration to my rails application. It's currently deployed with Capistrano, and I need to introduce at least one machine-specific variable -- a hostname, so that performance characteristics can be properly tracked. In the future, there are likely going to be further local differences. The code is deployed to a 3 node load balanced cluster from the same git repo.

What is the best way to manage machine specific config?

Comment: Capistrano offers the concept of so-called stages. Basically every machine gets its own config file in your `config/deploy` directory. Use that machine's name as the first element in a Capistrano call. E.g. when you have a file `config/deploy/alpharomeo.rb` you would use `cap alpharomeo deploy`. Dunno exactly how to deploy to multiple stages simultaneously. If you use a different tool to set up your machines, e.g. chef, then consider using that tool to install a bunch of machine specific settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can set environment variables in Capistrano config file, and fetch it in your rails app.

### config/deploy/.rb

```
%w[
  node1.example.com
  node2.example.com
  node3.example.com
].each do |host|
  server host, roles: %w[app], default_env: {hostname: host}
end
```

Then you can access the hostname with `ENV['HOSTNAME']`.